# How do I declare a variable or const for a module

Tags: excel, vba, variables, constants

how do I declare a variable (or constant?), so only the procedures in the current module can read it? For example:

```
Option Explicit

Private const dataPath as String = "..."
Private const dataFile as String = "File.xlsm"
Private const dataSheet as String = "Sheet1"

Sub GetData()
Dim WB as Workbook
Dim wsSet as Worksheet

Set WB = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
Set wsSet = WB.Worksheets("Settings")

Workbooks.Open Filename:=dataPath & "\" & dataFile

Workbooks(dataFile).Sheets(dataSheet).Range("A:A").Copy
wsSet.Range("D:D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Workbooks(dataFile).Close SaveChanges:=False

WB.Save

MsgBox "Done.", vbOkOnly, "Well done"

Exit Sub
```

Is that the correct way? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's how.

Comment: Thank you, is it also possible to declare `Private Const wbThis as Workbook = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)` in any way?

Comment: The Workbook data type is not one of the allowable data types for constants.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/const-statement).